# Is there Android documentation for the handle messages and errors MediaPlayer outputs to the log?

Tags: android

Is there a doc for all the log codes that media player outputs somewhere?

I have looked and can't find a complete list. These two files have some of the codes, but not all of them. [MediaPlayer.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java) and [mediaplayer.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/donut-release/include/media/mediaplayer.h).

I can use these to partially parse codes such as "D/MediaPlayer: handleMessage msg:(1, 0, 0)". I know it is a log message for a prepared event but have no clue what the next two numbers are.

I also get messages like "D/MediaPlayer: handleMessage msg:(6, 0, 0)". What is the 6? It is not listed. Same with "D/MediaPlayer: handleMessage msg:(8, 0, 0)".

I have searched the MediaPlayer doc page. Nothing. How is one supposed to know what the media player is doing with such obscure codes?

Even worse, is when an error is thrown and you are left with obscure codes such as (1, -19). What error is this?!?!?!?!?!?! Seriously, what is wrong with Google that they can't make these codes public?

I have read through several pages on stackOverflow where there is no mention of the actual message conveyed by the error code. Am I perhaps overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checking AOSP code you should verify what version of file you are looking at.

Your header file is from Donut (API 4) released in 2009: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/donut-release/include/media/mediaplayer.h

And your MediaPlayer.java file is from 2013, as found by checking the commit it is tagged with: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301

If you found a recent version:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java

Then this section might be the most relevant:

```
private static final int MEDIA_NOP = 0; // interface test message
private static final int MEDIA_PREPARED = 1;
private static final int MEDIA_PLAYBACK_COMPLETE = 2;
private static final int MEDIA_BUFFERING_UPDATE = 3;
private static final int MEDIA_SEEK_COMPLETE = 4;
private static final int MEDIA_SET_VIDEO_SIZE = 5;
private static final int MEDIA_STARTED = 6;
private static final int MEDIA_PAUSED = 7;
private static final int MEDIA_STOPPED = 8;
private static final int MEDIA_SKIPPED = 9;
private static final int MEDIA_NOTIFY_TIME = 98;
private static final int MEDIA_TIMED_TEXT = 99;
private static final int MEDIA_ERROR = 100;
private static final int MEDIA_INFO = 200;
private static final int MEDIA_SUBTITLE_DATA = 201;
private static final int MEDIA_META_DATA = 202;
private static final int MEDIA_DRM_INFO = 210;
private static final int MEDIA_TIME_DISCONTINUITY = 211;
private static final int MEDIA_AUDIO_ROUTING_CHANGED = 10000;
```

Sadly Google has never formalized what the various codes mean, as you can see by looking at the Donut file they have changed over the history of Android. Provided the ODM/ROM builder hasn't changed the codes, you can look at where these log/message values comes from given Android's open source foundation.

Comment: Thank you. What about the error codes and the codes after the initial?

Comment: I would search for the appropriate area/function which would be generating them. If its on recent version you should be able to find them with online search tools, but then again I have in the past downloaded the full AOSP to my hard drive and let `grep` rip. At least on older versions of Android the ODM changed certain parts so that expected logs didn't make sense (I'm looking at you Samsung).

Comment: The second and third digit might be `NOP`, which stands for: no operation... but it could as well be arguments of `android.os.Message`. Just see where it logs that, which isn't inside `handleMessage()`, then you'll know for certain what they may stand for.